# Azure Function changes not deployed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a simple  Function App that I implemented in the Azure Portal.It's up and running fine.

Since I would like to further develop using VS I downloaded the sources, and have setup CI/CD using VSTS. Now when I make changes in VS and commit this, it successfully triggers a build and deploys.

When I check the Azure portal I do see the deployments. No errors anywhere. 
Only problem is the changes don't seem to be deployed because whenever I run the function I get same old output. I also downloaded the app content from the portal and checked the sources - still old ones.

So I'm really confused as to what got deployed and where and why is it not showing up. I did restart the app several times to no avail.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you downloaded the contents of the function again and confirmed the new sources were there (in the correct folder)? I've had the same issue a couple of weeks back and it was because the new files were placed in a wrong folder. You could enable all the `Clean deployment location` options. There are multiple locations in VSTS from where you can configure this. I'd say, enable all of them, just to make sure!

Comment: Which is the correct folder and where can I see the 'Clean deployment location' in VSTS?

Comment: There's the `Remove additional files at destination` option in the `Deploy Azure App Service` task, the `Clean` checkbox when building the solution and the `Clean` checkbox when retrieving the sources. I guess only the `Remove additional files at destination` is necessary for you to see if/where the new sources are deployed. I've had to spend quite some time on this also and are in the middle of writing a blogpost about it. But without more details of your setup I can't give any better advice or a possible solution.

Comment: strange. I don't see that option anywhere on the 'Azure App Service Deploy' task. My setup is as simple as it can get - just a simple C# Webhook triggered function which I am trying to deploy

Comment: If you go to `d:\home\site\wwwroot` in Kudu Console, do you see your changes? And are you using a precompiled C# app (VS 2017 function app model), or .csx files?

Comment: To create a VS project from an existing Function App I downloaded the .csx file and added it to and empty Function App project.Realized I hadn't set the 'Build action' to compile and doing so it obviously can't compile just a static function defined in a .csx file.Creating a fresh Function App using the wizard creates a .cs file and not a .csx file.So now I probably need to just copy the function code into a freshly created project.Any pointers on how to create a project for an existing Function App?Should I stick to .csx files or move to .cs files with attributes?How are .csx files processed?

Comment: What're tasks of build and release definition? Can you share the detail log files on the OneDrive?

Comment: I actually got it to work. I hadn't properly ported my existing function in the .csx file to a precompiled function in VS. The compiled assembly just did not have the class with my function.So when it got deployed guess the runtime detected no function in the assembly and kept my existing function,developed in the portal, intact. After fixing the project I could successfully deploy the function.